# Ceiling fan loose wire

Tags: electrical

I had a ceiling fan spark and trip the breakers (loose wire). When I took the fan down I was surprised to find 4 sets of wires coming thru. 3 sets of black and white wires and the a set with black, white, and bare. Of the 3 sets of black and white wires all of the blacks are caped and taped and only two of the white are done the same. The other white was the loose wire causing the issue. The question is  where does this lone white wire go?

Comment: Are the wires from the fan hooked up ?  Does the loose white wire have any  tape on it?

Comment: Currently the fan isn’t hooked up because I was going to go ahead and switch it out for a newer one.  No the white wire doesn’t have tape on it.

Comment: do you remember how it was wired up?

Comment: Pretty sure the fan was wired to the forth set of wires (black, white, and bare) the other 3 sets each containing black and white where wired as all blacks tied and caped and only two of the whites done the same, leaving the one lone white.

Comment: Thinking the cap fell off of the lone white one or something....were the black and white wires twisted together and capped as groups? or capped individually?

Comment: The blacks and whites are twisted, capped, and taped as groups.

Comment: Any chance we can get a photo of what's going on inside the switch?

Comment: Can we have photos of the insides of the light and switch boxes please?

Comment: By the way, the root cause is not knowing how to do wire nuts properly  .  That is why they are wrapped with tape.  They fall apart if  not wrapped.  That means they are poorly spliced,  and an arc fault risk. Nuts should survive a pull test.